# @Autowired on methods

Tags: spring, annotations, autowired

I have a code containing the below snippet running:

```
class MyNewReader implements ItemReader<MyBean>, ItemStream{    
@Resource
SingleItemPeekableItemReader<MyBean> myBeanPeekableReader;

@Resource
public void setDelegate(MyJdbcReader myJdbcReader){
     myBeanPeekableReader.setDelegate(myJdbcReader);
}
```

I don't have any property delegate in my class MyNewReader.
    But still the annotation @Resource is working on setDelegate method and is working fine.
    Can someone tell that is it not necessary to have a property in the class to let annotation on setter method(having that property in its name) work...Is this not working as setter injection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`myBeanPeekableReader.setDelegate(myJdbcReader)` gets its jdbcReader injected as parameter to the method you have annotated.

Yes, setter injection.

Comment: Yes, you are right. But I have no property of the name delegate in my class MyNewReader still the resource annotation works. So is it not necessary to have property of the name delegate in our class to let that annotation work. Talking particularly of @Resource on setDelegate method.

Comment: @user2971387 yes. Although generally you normally do. But this wouldn't be a problem. Its just calling a setter with an argument.

Comment: I just changed the name of the method setDelegate in my class MyNewReader tocaller. And it still works. Does this mean autowiring on any method( not just setter method) works fine and injection of method argument takes place successfully.

Comment: @user2971387 yes, but that doesn't mean its a good idea to rename your setters to something else. the annotation just injects the paraemter wherever you tell it.